# React handling api params not showing

Tags: reactjs, api, parameters

This is my column.
I need the href from api that contains customers id. I'm currently using reactTable and everything is working fine. But only the params are not handled down when I look inside my console.
Can anyone tell me what's missing?

```
const columns = [
  {
    Header: '',
    accessor: 'links[0].href',
    filterable: false,
    sortable: false,
    Cell: ({params}) => <Button color="secondary" onClick={()=>deleteCustomer(params)}>Delete</Button>
  }
];

const deleteCustomer = (params) => {
  console.log(params)
};

const getCustomer = () => {
  fetch('https://customerrest.herokuapp.com/api/customers')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => setCustomer(data.content))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
};
```

Here is an example API call:

```
    {
      "links" : [ {
        "rel" : "self",
        "href" : "https://customerrest.herokuapp.com/api/customers"
      }, {
        "rel" : "profile",
        "href" : "https://customerrest.herokuapp.com/api/profile/customers"
      } ],
      "content" : [ {
        "firstname" : "Mark",
        "lastname" : "Johnson",
        "streetaddress" : "5th Street",
        "postcode" : "23110",
        "city" : "Flintsone",
        "email" : "john@mail.com",
        "phone" : "232-2345540",
        "content" : [ ],
        "links" : [ {
          "rel" : "self",
          "href" : "https://customerrest.herokuapp.com/api/customers/620"
        }, {
          "rel" : "customer",
          "href" : "https://customerrest.herokuapp.com/api/customers/620"
        }, {
          "rel" : "trainings",
          "href" : "https://customerrest.herokuapp.com/api/customers/620/trainings"
        } ]
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think react-table provides "params" in the callback of Cell option. try to pass the param without curly bracket, and then pick the data that you need

`Cell: (params) => <Button color="secondary" onClick={()=>deleteCustomer(params)}>Delete</Button>`

Answer (score 0):

Pass params in your onClick handle func.:

```
Cell: ({params}) => <Button color="secondary" onClick={(params)=>deleteCustomer(params)}>Delete</Button>
```